# python mechanize - can login to site but can't grab html for a list of URLs?

Tags: python, html, url, loops, mechanize

I've written the following in python using the mechanize module in order to print out the HTML from a list URLs:

```
import mechanize, fileinput

urls = open('F:\Python\url_list.txt')
content = [x.strip() for x in urls.readlines()]
print content

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("https://login.asp")
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser['desc'] = "xxxxx"
browser['password'] = "xxxxx"
response = browser.submit()
logincheck = response.read()

print logincheck

# now logged into site, loop through the list of urls read in from the text file and print the html for each one:

for s in content:

    releasenote = browser.urlopen(s) 
    # error here, should be releasenote = browser.open(s)

    print  releasenote.geturl()
    print  releasenote.info()
    print  releasenote.read()
```

I'm just getting the following error in the python shell however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Python\test.py", line 20, in <module>
releasenote = browser.urlopen(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 628, in __getattr__
".select_form()?)" % (self.__class__, name))
AttributeError: mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance has no attribute urlopen (perhaps you forgot to .select_form()?)
```

What am I doing wrong? Cheers!

Comment: Try creating a new browser just before the for loop and use that new browser within the for loop. I think that selecting the form might have somehow changed the state of the browser to bring you this error. I'm not entirely sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `mechanize.urlopen(s)`

or as you said `browser.open(s)`.

Comment: found my mistake!:
`releasenote = browser.urlopen(s)` should have been:
`releasenote = browser.open(s)`
what a dumbass *rolleyes*

Comment: @4rd2: please mark this answer as the one solving your problem; thanks.